# What is wrong with this Python code?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?  I'm getting a syntax error after the 2nd quote on the `print` line...  It seems like this should work perfectly fine.  Thanks

```
def main():
    print "blah"
    return


main()
```

Comment: Works fine for me, I am using Python 2.6.4

Comment: Tell us what the syntax error is.

Comment: Syntax error on `print`?  Are you using Python 3?  `print` is a function, not a statement.  Should be `print("blah")`.

Comment: ahhh yeah, I'm using Python 3...

Comment: I guess I should have went for the answer instead of the comment.

Comment: @Jeff M, Yeah, I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you're using Python 3, the `print` statement is gone in that version and you need to use the `print()` function.

See: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Answer (score 4):

You're using python 3.

use

```
print("blah")
```

The `print` statement turned into the `print` function in the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Remember if your using python 2.x then to help with the transition you can always have

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

At the top of your code, this will convert print into a function meaning 2.x code can be written with

```
print('This')
```

And run happily

Answer (score 0):

Posting the exact error you get would be very helpful. I'm going to assume that this is an indentation error though. Don't mix tabs and spaces.